# StackOverflow for BlackBerry10

Tags: app

#### About

This is an initiative to build a true native StackOverflow app for BlackBerry 10 platform. Currently, this app is under rapid development and testing phase and aiming for a public release in BlackBerry World. This is to target users who use BlackBerry 10 OS enabled devices and experience native BlackBerry 10 and Cascades experience out of the box.

#### Platform

BlackBerry 10 OS.

#### Contact

StackOverflow for BlackBerry 10 contains contributions from Shimul Chowdhury (Product requirements, design, testing) and Mengdu Li (Lead developer).

#### Code

Written in C++ (Qt), and developed using BlackBerry Cascades SDK (Momentincs).